# Passing Numpy array to C with Ctypes differs between Linux and Windows

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I am trying to pass a Numpy array into C, but get different results in Windows and Linux.

In Python

```
import platform
import numpy as np
import ctypes

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    c_fun = np.ctypeslib.load_library("/mypath/c_fun.dll", ".").c_fun
else:    # Linux
    c_fun = np.ctypeslib.load_library("/mypath/c_fun.so", ".").c_fun
c_fun.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.int, ndim=2, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"), ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

array = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
rows, cols = array.shape
c_fun(array, rows, cols)
```

In C

```
void c_fun(int* array, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

When I run the program in Windows, the output is "0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0", it works well.

But in Linux, the output is "0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1", why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `numpy.int`. It's just `int`, not any sort of NumPy thing. I think it's there for backward compatibility.

NumPy converts Python ints to dtype `numpy.int_` (note the underscore) by default, and `numpy.int_` corresponds to C **`long`**, not C `int`. Your code thus only works when C `int` and `long` are the same size, which they are on Windows, but not Linux.